# What's the difference between Mix_Chunk and Mix_Music?

Tags: audio, sdl, sdl-mixer

When should I use `Mix_Chunk` instead of `Mix_Music`?

Answer (score 10):

`SDL_mixer` supports playing both **samples** and **music**. The documentation puts it this way:

> SDL_mixer is a sample multi-channel audio mixer library.
>
> It supports any number of simultaneously playing channels of 16 bit stereo audio, plus a single channel of music

Since playing both types of audio are supported, there is a structure fo each type.

- The `Mix_Chunk` structure represents a sample, or in other words a sound effect.
- The `Mix_Music` structure represents a piece of music, something that can be played for an extended period of time, usually repeated.

When you want to play sound effects, you would use a [`Mix_Chunk` and it's associated functions](http://www.libsdl.org/projects/SDL_mixer/docs/SDL_mixer.html#SEC16). When you want to play music, you would use a [`Mix_Music` and it's associated functions](http://www.libsdl.org/projects/SDL_mixer/docs/SDL_mixer.html#SEC52).

It's important to remember that you can play multiple samples at once, but you can only play one music at a time.

Comment: Whats the actual difference between them though? Why wouldn't I want to use a Mix_Chunk to play an extended audio file? It seems like Mix_Music is strictly less powerful than Mix_Chunk and has no benefit? Does it stream the audio or something? Is there a reason you're limited to just one?

Comment: @Alex, The audio quality of Mix_Chunk and Mix_Music greatly differ.  Mix_Music has a better quality while Mix_Chunk gives off audio that sound like its frequencies were limited, thus, giving off a somewhat broken sound as compared to Mix_Music.

Answer (score 7):

Mix_Chunk is used for playing sound samples, while Mix_Music is meant to play music.

One key difference between the two is that multiple Mix_Chunk can be played at once on different sound channels, whereas only one Mix_Music may be played at the time.

For example, if you're programming a game, you'd want to use Mix_Music for the background music and Mix_Chunk for sound effects (lasers, powerups, etc.)

[More info](http://www.cs.clemson.edu/~malloy/courses/3dgames-2007/tutor/web/audio/audio.html)